# What is the exact purpose of this 2.2kOhm resistor in the circuit?

Tags: voltage, led, resistors, integrated-circuit, ground

[image: Dark activated LED]

My best guess is that it's there to drop the voltage down to 0V by the time the current reaches the negative terminal but I'm not sure if that's the case; and if it is, is it absolutely necessary to be there and why exactly? Also a side question: Why is the voltage dropped to 5V in the beginning of the circuit, wouldn't it work if it remained 9V?

Comment: A 741 will not run from 5V. This question is flawed - read the data sheet.

Comment: opamps don't make good comparators, and 741's aren't good opamps (particularly in low-voltage single-supply circuits).

Comment: [Why Not 741 op-amp](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/217834/can-i-use-a-ua741-here/217973#217973)  for background on why not

Comment: @Andyaka Why wouldn't a 741 work here? Its inputs will be very close to VCC/2, and the output only has to go low enough and high enough to turn off/on the LED. The short-circuit current is large enough to make the LED turn on.

Comment: Ok, I guess what I've got from the link Marla supplied is that the 741 is generally a pretty old ic and is not reliable especially on a voltage below 7 volts to even power an LED. It is not a good comparator for this circuit but I'm new to electrical engineering so I would appreciate if someone gave an example of an ic I can use for this specific purpose. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @user3423386 _Any_ operational amplifier does a better job. :) The cheapest and most available alternative is probably the LM324.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the recommendation, pipe. I looked into it and I guess I'll take your word for it. I guess the LM324 really is a better choice. :)

Comment: @pipe - read the data sheet in the link you posted in your answer and look at the table of recommended operating conditions. I shall be passing a container around later and I expect everyone to throw their old 741s into it. They will be donated to some audiophile club.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the exact purpose of this 2.2 kOhm resistor in the circuit?
>   [...] is it absolutely necessary to be there and why exactly?

Its purpose is to form a *voltage divider* with [LDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoresistor) (photoresistor). The resistance of LDR varies with the light intensity. The resistor turns the variable *resistance* into a variable *voltage*, which is then compared to a reference voltage that you can control with the potentiometer.

Yes, it's necessary in this circuit, and most other circuits using an LDR.

> Why is the voltage dropped to 5V in the beginning of the circuit, wouldn't it work if it remained 9V?

You're right here. Due to the circuit's construction of only relying on the *relative* resistances, the circuit would work fine (even better) without the regulation. You would only have to change the resistor after the LED, because the output from the operational amplifier will be closer to 9 volts than 5 volts.

One minor benefit of having a 5 volt regulation is that you will only get at most 5 volts out of the operational amplifier. This could be useful if you want to connect it straight to a digital input.

Note that the μA741 amplifier chosen here is a pretty bad choice, but why it is so is [another question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/217834/can-i-use-a-ua741-here/217973#217973).

Answer (score 3):

This question wasn't asked but I thought it might be useful information for you.

Why is it a 2.2K resistor? Can I just use any resistor?

It's all a matter of sensitivity, the LDR will be the most sensitive to light changes in both light and dark if your fixed resistor is a similar resistance to the midway point of the LDR.

I've plotted a little graph so you can see the effect of using different fixed resistors for the LDR in your circuit schematic

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was just about to research this and you saved me a lot of time with this information. I think I kind of understand voltage dividers now. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The sensor is a LDR, which changes resistance when exposed to light.  The circuit is a operational amplifier, used as a comparator, that will turn on an LED when a certain level of light is reached.

Comparators respond to voltage, not resistance, so somehow, the resistance value of the LDR must be converted to a voltage.  There are a few ways to do this.  One, which is not real common, is to use a constant current source, and then the voltage across the LDR would be proportional to it's resistance.

Another way to is put the LDR into a voltage divider.  The 2.2 KOhms forms the lower half of the voltage divider.

Comment: This, though, is NOT a voltage divider; it is a Wheatstone bridge, and that has advantages (not sensitive to the exciting voltage, for instance: the regulator might be wholly eliminated).

Comment: @Whit3rd A wheatstone bridge is just two voltage dividers.  Unless all the arms are together, and the differential signals run together so most noise is common mode, you lose many of the benefits.  Also, a Wheatstone bridge is actually pretty sensitive to changes in excitation voltage (sensitivity is usually given in volts per volt excitation), and precision bridge amplifiers use feedback to stabilize excitation or excite with constant current.  Lastly, there's very little point in using a Wheatstone bridge to drive a comparator

Comment: See page 4.9 in https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.analog.com/library/analogDialogue/archives/39-05/Web_Ch4_final.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwitoczswabOAhUG6iYKHR0wDEoQFgggMAE&usg=AFQjCNFW9Ji2uW9pRlNEU8sRSv5nyghcQg&sig2=tWtxZwsVJa9fQG3vZaNuTQ about how excitation voltage is in all the configurations, and figure 4-17 to see how excitation Volare is served to stabilize

Comment: A Wheatstone sensed by a comparator with very high gain is NOT sensitive to excitation (though zero excitation, or polarity reversal,